# PostgreSQL error codes

Tags: postgresql, exception, error-handling

Where can I find the list of exceptions supported by Postgres? Like in oracle there are exceptions - When no_data_found, when divide_by_zero, when others etc..

Comment: This is two completely unrelated questions.  Please ask them as two questions.

Comment: @Flimzy: I deleted one of the two questions to make this a valid post.

Answer (score 3):

The list of PostgreSQL error codes can be found in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/errcodes-appendix.html